# Font's in WinRT are not working

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have WINRT App and I have list of fonts, which i want to add. I added them to my solution and try to set FontFamily to TextBlock. And I found out that only part of them is working. Can you explain me why, is it a bug of WinRT apps?

Comment: What did you do? Can you show some code?

Comment: What do you mean by 'only part of them is working'? Do some of the fonts work but others don't?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make the fonts as a static resource in the App.xaml page.. 
But mostly it'll not work, I've this problem.. some of my favorite fonts are working but a big part of my fonts won't working for some reasons !